# Pip install pycaret-pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully

Tags: anaconda, pycaret

I am using Anaconda and trying to install pycaret but it's always stuck on Installing Build dependencies after which this error comes out. subprocess-exited-with-error

```
Collecting scikit-learn==0.23.2
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.23.2.tar.gz (7.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [669 lines of output]
```

```
    Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation != "CPython"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-65.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting Cython>=0.28.5
        Using cached Cython-0.29.33-py2.py3-none-any.whl (987 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.17.3
        Using cached numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting scipy>=0.19.1
        Using cached scipy-1.10.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (42.5 MB)
        Using cached scipy-1.9.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (40.2 MB)
        Using cached scipy-1.9.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (40.1 MB)
        Using cached scipy-1.9.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (38.6 MB)
        Using cached scipy-1.9.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (38.6 MB)
        Using cached scipy-1.8.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (36.9 MB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
        Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [292 lines of output]
        Running from numpy source directory.
        blas_opt_info:
        blas_mkl_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        blis_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
        get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
        customize GnuFCompiler
        Could not locate executable g77
        Could not locate executable f77
        customize IntelVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable ifort
        Could not locate executable ifl
        customize AbsoftFCompiler
        Could not locate executable f90
        customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable DF
        customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable efl
        customize Gnu95FCompiler
        Could not locate executable gfortran
        Could not locate executable f95
        customize G95FCompiler
        Could not locate executable g95
        customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
        customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
        Could not locate executable efort
        Could not locate executable efc
        customize PGroupFlangCompiler
        Could not locate executable flang
        don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_blas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_blas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        accelerate_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\jchieng004\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-56y3ln9c\numpy_1b9548e07549442b85177a775870c713\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
            Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
            Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
            A better performance should be easily gained by switching
            Blas library.
          self.calc_info()
        blas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\jchieng004\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-56y3ln9c\numpy_1b9548e07549442b85177a775870c713\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
            the BLAS environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
        blas_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\jchieng004\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-56y3ln9c\numpy_1b9548e07549442b85177a775870c713\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
            the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
          NOT AVAILABLE

        'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
        operable program or batch file.
        non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
        lapack_opt_info:
        lapack_mkl_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_lapack_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_clapack_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        flame_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\libs
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\libs
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\Library\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\Library\lib
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\libs
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\libs
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\Library\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\Library\lib
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\libs
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\libs
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\Library\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\Library\lib
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\libs
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\envs\jcdemopycaret\libs
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\Library\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\jchieng004\Anaconda3\Library\lib
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        lapack_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\envs\\jcdemopycaret\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\jchieng004\\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\jchieng004\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-56y3ln9c\numpy_1b9548e07549442b85177a775870c713\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
            the LAPACK environment variable.
          if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
        lapack_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\jchieng004\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-56y3ln9c\numpy_1b9548e07549442b85177a775870c713\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
            the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
          if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
          NOT AVAILABLE
```

I am new to the coding and just install the Anaconda last week. I try to install the pycaret in the virtual environment based on the youtube tutorial and website . However, the error still exist and not sure which part i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

pycaret works well with pip. Can you use pip for installation.

`pip install --pre pycaret`